# Having trouble with Group By function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Why is mySQL function returning `not a single group function error`?

```
SELECT order#, TO_CHAR(quantity*paideach, '$999.99') AS "Order Total"
FROM orderitems
GROUP BY order#;
```

Comment: Hi Mitch, if an answer helps you, click the green "tick" icon next to it to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Mitch . . . This is a really good example of why sample data, desired results and an explanation are needed.  It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish, and your question really gives no hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to sum the paid amounts?  Try this version:

```
SELECT order#, TO_CHAR(SUM(quantity*paideach), '$999.99') AS "Order Total"
FROM orderitems
GROUP BY order#;
```

You are seeing this error because you have instructed Oracle to aggregate your `orderitems` table by `order#`.  This means that it will report aggregates of all records for a given order, so it doesn't make sense to select the `quantity*paideach`, which is a property of a single record.  Taking the sum should fix this error.

Comment: I added the SUM and it corrected the error. Thank you for the help.

Comment: give it a green tick

Comment: @nikhilsugandh I don't like grovelling for points (nor do I need any more points), but I ask because it damages the SO database to have dangling questions with no accepted answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i agree   can i get your fb account link because i want to talk to you about oracle i work in Oracle apps and your top tag is sql

Comment: Just Google for my name...there are only 2 people on the planet who have my name, AFAIK.